# Camera module in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I'm using Rasberry Pi 3 along with a camera module. The camera is being detected but when I run raspistill to save an image no data is received.

I checked the connection at both ends.

Is the camera module a faulty one? How can i make sure whether this works or not?

Comment: What is the camera version?
Have u enabled the camera in interface?
When running raspistill -o cam.jpg
What kind of error it shows?...

Comment: Im having camera version 1.3 . and while running the rasistill -o cam.jpg im getting no data obtained from the sensor please check the connections , ive checked it its good .

Comment: @ And Currently im getting Failed to enable connected port ENOSPC .PicameraMMALError:Failed to enable connection

Comment: Check the lights.
The red light on the camera module should glow.

Comment: Yes the Red light on the camera module keeps glowing in the old module , now its fixed .  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the camera is most likely faulty, as I bought another one and it does not have this problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.